# Eigenvectors and linear operators (Mistake)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was solving the following problem from Artin and think there might be a mistake

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ such that $T^2$ is the identity operator. Prove that for any $v\in V$, $v-T(v)$ is either $0_V$ or is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$.

My attempt: Since $T(v)=\lambda v$. We substitute this in out expression which yields $v-\lambda v$ =0. This implies $v=0$ or $\lambda=1$. Thus is there a mistake in the question asked as we get our eigenvalue 1 and not -1

Comment: Who says $T(v)=\lambda v$? There's no assumption that $v$ is an eigenvector. You're supposed to _conclude_ that $v-T(v)$ (not $v$) is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $v-T(v)$ is not $0_V$.  Then $T(v-T(v))=T(v)-T(T(v))=T(v)-v$ (since $T^2$ is the identity operator).  In particular, $T(v-T(v))=-(v-T(v))$, which shows that $v-T(v)$ is an eigenvector (since it is non-zero) with eigenvalue $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can rewrite
$$
v - T(v) = (I - T)v
$$
Where $I$ is the identity matrix.  Now, show that
$$
T(v - T(v)) = \cdots = -(v - T(v))
$$